# Add Opp Team Member Whose Role is Portfolio Developer to Local Portfolio developer field in Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger

**Code:**

```
trigger AssignCloseOppTeamMember on OpportunityTeamMember (after insert) {
    List<Opportunity> OpportunityList = new List<Opportunity>();
    Map<Id, Id> OppIdOppMemberIdMap = new Map<Id, Id>();

    for(OpportunityTeamMember OpportunityTeamMemberObj: Trigger.New){
        if(OpportunityTeamMemberObj.TeamMemberRole =='Portfolio Developer')

            OppIdOppMemberIdMap.put(OpportunityTeamMemberObj.OpportunityId , OpportunityTeamMemberObj.Id);
    }

    for(Opportunity opportunityObj : [Select Id, LocalPortfolioDeveloper__c from Opportunity where Id IN: OppIdOppMemberIdMap.keyset()]){
        if(OppIdOppMemberIdMap.Containskey(opportunityObj.Id)){
            opportunityObj.LocalPortfolioDeveloper__c= OppIdOppMemberIdMap.get(opportunityObj.Id).UserId;
            OpportunityList.add(opportunityObj);
            }
        }
    update OpportunityList;

    }
```

**Error Message:**

> Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Id at
>   line 13 column 95

Answer (score 0):

You have declared

```
Map<Id, Id> OppIdOppMemberIdMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
```

And, preparing the map like this:

```
OppIdOppMemberIdMap.put(OpportunityTeamMemberObj.OpportunityId , OpportunityTeamMemberObj.Id);
```

so far good.

Error in this line

```
opportunityObj.LocalPortfolioDeveloper__c= OppIdOppMemberIdMap.get(opportunityObj.Id).UserId;
```

Basically,

`OppIdOppMemberIdMap.get(opportunityObj.Id)` returns the `Id` of `OpportunityTeamMemberObj` record.

> Now, `Id.userId` doesn't make any sense and it returns the error

Correct code will be:

```
for(Opportunity opportunityObj : [Select Id, LocalPortfolioDeveloper__c from Opportunity where Id IN: OppIdOppMemberIdMap.keyset()]){
    if(OppIdOppMemberIdMap.Containskey(opportunityObj.Id)){
        opportunityObj.LocalPortfolioDeveloper__c= OppIdOppMemberIdMap.get(opportunityObj.Id);
        OpportunityList.add(opportunityObj);
        }
    }
update OpportunityList;

}
```